# Java Swing - Copy / Paste doesn't work when in Java Web Start

Tags: java, swing, java-web-start

I created a textfield in Java Swing

```
txtSessionID = new JTextField();
txtSessionID.setText("enter here");
txtSessionID.setBounds(6, 22, 438, 28);
frame.getContentPane().add(txtSessionID);
```

When I try to copy something into the textfield it works if I run the jar on desktop but not if I start it with Java Web Start.

The Question:

Why is this so?
And
How do I make CCP work in the JWS forms?

Comment: I think it has to do something with signing the jar if you start it from the web directly (via WebStart). Only signed jars can access the clipboard.

Comment: Ok, I added the question :) I'm sorry if it wasn't obvious what I was after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the altered behaviour can be found in [Copy in sand-boxed app. in 1.6.0_24+](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2197433).  The security bug fix applies to both applets & JWS apps.

The solution (again outlined in the linked thread) is to use the JNLP API's `ClipboardService` instead.  Here is a [demo. of the ClipboardService](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#cbs).

Comment: It works. However I ran into a problem testing it. It needs to be ran from JNLP to test it not from IDE. I was getting a javax.jnlp.UnavailableServiceException: uninitialized. ANy ideas how to test from IDE?

Comment: I don't typically use an IDE, but I'll bite.  Which one, and can it build Ant based projects?  Did you manage to run the code of the demo. from your IDE?

Comment: Eclipse, can build Ant. I didn't run the demo code in it, just looked at the code and recreated similar in mine.

Comment: Well, Eclipse can run that demo. in your IDE, and it can run your own project the same way.  Perhaps your IDE even has a project specific to developing JWS apps., but the Ant build will work will always work as an alternate.

Comment: I'll fiddle with it then. In the mean time, do I have to do anything special in Eclipse, new run configuration or something else?

Comment: I don't know.  Like I said, I don't use Eclipse.  Maybe you should ask a dedicated question re. Eclipse/JWS.

Comment: No luck with Eclipse, with neither of examples. However you can run it locally if you specify "codebase" attribute to a local file system with "file:///Users/bla/project/" or wherever your jar lives. There is very little info on this to be found.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer copy from textfield to another

```
public class GuiFrame1 {

    private JFrame frame;

    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GuiFrame1 window = new GuiFrame1();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public GuiFrame1() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel NewLabel_1 = new JLabel("\u03A0\u03B1\u03C1\u03B1\u03BA\u03B1\u03BB\u03CE \u03B5\u03B9\u03C3\u03AC\u03B3\u03B5\u03C4\u03B5 \u03C4\u03BF \u03CC\u03BD\u03BF\u03BC\u03AC \u03C3\u03B1\u03C2");
        NewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 11, 191, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(NewLabel_1);

        JLabel NewLabel_2 = new JLabel("\u03A4\u03BF \u03CC\u03BD\u03BF\u03BC\u03AC \u03BC\u03BF\u03C5 \u03B5\u03AF\u03BD\u03B1\u03B9");
        NewLabel_2.setBounds(10, 63, 191, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(NewLabel_2);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            //  System.out.println(arg0.getKeyCode());
                if(arg0.getKeyCode()==10) {
                    String name = textField_1.getText();
                    textField_2.setText(name);
                }
            }
        });

        textField_1.setBounds(228, 8, 119, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setBounds(228, 60, 119, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField_2);
        textField_2.setColumns(10);
    }
}
```